# image should stay permanent if I edit in both the the columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Whenever I edit the check boxes I need to show the `timeGrad1` image in `editImage` column.

Right now if I edit checkbox in third column image shows after that if I edit the checkbox in sixth column the image disappears, but the image should stay permanent if I edit in both the the columns. Similarly it should happen for the drop down menu too.

Can you tell me how to fix, so that in future I will fix it by myself?

Providing my code below

http://jsfiddle.net/61ufvtpj/

```or-tag-here
$(document).on('change', '#sixthColumnCheck', function() {

  if (this.checked) {
    alert("if I am inside sixth column");
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(1).addClass("timeGrad1");
    var returnVal = confirm("Are you sure?");
    $(this).prop("checked", returnVal);
  } else {
    alert("else I am inside sixth column");

    $(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(1).removeClass("timeGrad1");

  }

});

//thirdColumnCheckGrid


$(document).on('change', '#thirdColumnCheckGrid', function() {

  if (this.checked) {
    alert("if I am inside third column");
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(1).addClass("timeGrad1");
    var returnVal = confirm("Are you sure?");
    $(this).prop("checked", returnVal);
  } else {
    alert("else I am inside third column");

    $(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(1).removeClass("timeGrad1");

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the required td element already have "timeGrad1" class.

like this ,

```
if(!$(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(1).hasClass("timeGrad1"))
{         
   $(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(1).removeClass("timeGrad1");
}
```

if class is already applied then don't remove image from td otherwise remove it.

refer this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/61ufvtpj/1/

Hope this will meet your requirement !!!

Comment: Can you please clear your requirement on change of drop down.

Comment: hey when we select another drop down the same image should show up in the second column

Comment: hey I am not able to test it properly...can you adjust the width of the grid...I edited css in developer tools but still its not moving http://jsfiddle.net/61ufvtpj/2/embedded/#Result

Comment: can you explain the if condition too...if it doesnt have timeGrad1 class your removing timeGrad1 inside the if....can you tell me how its working...so that in future I can fix it by myself

Comment: hey if I unlick in sixth column that time also image should stay...right now its not staying...any idea how to fix it...jsfiddle.net/61ufvtpj/2